# Non-exact Vlookup with multiple search criteria - Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm having a problem extracting some date from a table in Excel. The data is in the format shown in the diagram below:

```
Name---------------------------First Name------------------- Surname
Billy Peter Hunt---------------Tim---------------------------Smith
Chris Paul Smith---------------Brad--------------------------Johnson
Dave Colin Jones---------------Karen-------------------------Perry
Dr James Clyde Watt------------Dave--------------------------Jones
John Phil Cross----------------Chris-------------------------Smith
Kelly Holmes-------------------Hector------------------------Baxter
Norman Bryce-West--------------Billy-------------------------Hunt
```

For each person listed in the `First Name` and `Surname` columns (e.g. "Tim Smith", "Brad Johnson" etc) I want to be able to search through the `Name` column, for the first cell that contains both the `First Name` AND `Surname` of the person being searched for, and output the results into a new column.

As there are lots of middle names, titles and double-barreled surnames in the `Name` column, I can't use an exact match search. I need to search the contents of each cell to see if they have any matching sub-strings.

I've found that I can use `Vlookup` with wildcards to search based on either the `First Name` OR `Surname` columns, but I can't figure out how to use both columns simultaneously as search criteria.

Any help with this would be much appreciated. I've been typing all sorts into Google and making lots of frustrated grunts to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the array function:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$100,MATCH(9^99,SEARCH(B2,A$2:A$100)*SEARCH(C2,A$2:A$100)))
```

This will work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> but not with <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone.

Change `100` to any number you need depending on the number of rows you have (or change `A$2:A$100` to `A:A` to get the whole column, but it can be slower).

Note that if there are several people with names containing the same name and surname (e.g. `Tim Smith` and `Smith Tim`, the function will give you the last result from the column).

Comment: @pnuts Woops, right. The range shouldn't change when the formula is filled down.

Comment: @pnuts You have no idea how long it took to evaluate with `A:A`! Well, a few seconds, but still! x3

Comment: You could possibly do first name/last name search within the same SEARCH function, e.g. `=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(B2&"*"&C2,A$2:A$100),A$2:A$100)`

Comment: @barryhoudini Good point! I wanted to handle situations like `Tim Smith` and `Smith Tim` as well though, hence the separate `search`es. I really need to try shifting to lookup instead of index/match though!

Comment: @pnuts Thanks! I have a ways to go understand many of the insides of Excel ^^

Answer (score 0):

Could try:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("*"&B2&"*"&C2,A:A,0),"")
```

[image: SO18771894 example]

where the resulting number is the row where the components First Name and Surname match.

(Will not cover every possibility though unlikely there is any automated way to do that. For example, will point to Timothy J Smithson in preference to Tim Smith when Tim Smith is present but lower down the ColumnA list.)

Formula adjusted since image taken, as final wildcard might be more of a hindrance than a help.